# SQL: group by -1 is doing nothing with grouping by other columns?

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by

I have the following part of group by expression

```
group by a, c, (case when a='F' then b else '-1' end)
```

### I don't want group by b if a isn't equal to 'F', when I was using 1 instead -1 there was difference in query results, I don't see difference when I using 1, but I don't know, will -1 change query results or is there other more readable way of doing it?

Sorry, there was a typo in my query, really query wasn't the same, in program I haven't got it, now everything is correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you only want to `group by` `b` under some conditions, then don't include `b` in the `group by`.  Instead:

```
group by a, c, (case when a = 'F' then b end)
```

I would leave out the `else` clause entirely, but this could get confusing if `b` is `NULL`.  If you can find a value that `b` never takes on, you can include that in the `group by`.  Otherwise, you can add an additional component to the logic:

```
group by a, c,
         (case when a = 'F' then b end),
         (case when a = 'F' and b is null then 1 else 2 end)
```

Of course, this would produce two `NULL` rows, one for the real `NULL` and one for the non-matching.  You can take care of that distinction in the `select`.

Comment: Thanks! I wasn't thinking just about remove else clause.

Answer (score 0):

Your query is grouping by **`b`** because you  have the column **`b`** listed in the `GROUP BY` clause:

```
GROUP BY a, b, c, CASE WHEN a='F' THEN b ELSE '-1' END
            ^
```

Remove that column reference, and replace it with the CASE expression, e.g.:

```
GROUP BY a, CASE WHEN a='F' THEN b ELSE '-1' END, c
```